# Knockout: can observable extenders be called without parameters?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In Knockout.js, the typical syntax for invoking an observable extender is as follows:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable('foo').extend({myExtenderKey: myExtenderOption});
```

However, what if I have an extender that doesn't take a parameter? A simple logger, for instance, might not need any arguments. Nor would an auto-updating 'hasChanged' flag.

Most examples in the wild just pass an unused boolean:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable('foo').extend({logsChanges : true});
```

This looks nice because a naive reader will guess that a `logsChanges` behaviour is being activated. But the boolean is misleading, because the following will also work:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable('foo').extend({logsChanges : false});
```

We could also pass a null value, but it seems a little redundant:

```
this.myObservable = ko.observable('foo').extend({logsChanges : null});
```

It also implies that a parameter *might* be sent to the logsChanges extender, even when it should never be.

Is there a way of calling an extender that doesn't include the extra parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source for `extend`](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/253559691a47cda11bdc1d306723a992c290735c/src/subscribables/extenders.js#L72-L83) it does not appear to be the case right now.  Baring a pull request, that's just how things work.

However, what you *could* do is update your extender to actually honor the boolean:

```
function logsChanges(target, shouldLog) {
  if (!shouldLog) return target;
  // Alternatively, you could return `false`
  // but returning `target` is more explicit
  return function loggingHandler() {
    // Log changes and update here.
  };
}
```

Comment: This seems the best way to ensure transparency; I'll use this going forwards.